# Make videos playable just in my app

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app which contents should be downloaded from a server. After downloading videos, I want to prevent them from publishing or sharing. I searched about this and find out that putting a dot (.) before the name of the video will hide it from file manager and gallery. But if the user uses a professional file manager would see the videos!
I want a solution to make videos unplayable via other apps.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I Know, you could put your files in your internal directory which is private and only your app can access it.

but still, devices with root access can view and edit your files.

you can get private file location via `context.getFilesDir()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use cache directory instead of External storage

Ex:

```
File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DEFAULT_CACHE_DIR);
```

each app has own cached directory and can accessible only for that app (unless root)
That one simple way to hide media from other apps

[more](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.content.Context/getCacheDir)